# Edição de dados em PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Olá, estou com um problema em meu código que não encontrei o problema.

Ao tentar editar o ID 1750 ele executa mas salva no ID 0, gostaria de saber se meu código possui algum erro neste sentido, por que ao clicar em editar na linha que desejo ele acessa e puxa os dados dela mas quando tento salvar ele sempre vai no ID 0.

Erro que apresenta 
**Warning**:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in **C:\xampp\htdocs\eletrictel\painel\projetos_editar.php** on line **244**

````
// Classe Projeto Editar.php
<?php
include('../class/classe_verifica_login.php');
include_once('../class/classe_conexao.php');
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$result_empresa = "SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
$resultado_empresa = mysqli_query($conexao, $result_empresa);
$row_empresa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_empresa);
?>

<form method="POST" action="projeto_editar.php">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="bmd-label-floating">ID ( Desabilitado )</label>
              //linha 244          <input type="text" name="id" id="id" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row_empresa['id']; ?>" disabled>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="bmd-label-floating">Empresa</label>
                        <input name="nm_empresa" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_empresa['nm_empresa']; ?>" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="bmd-label-floating">Status</label>
                        <input name="pj_status" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_empresa['pj_status']; ?>" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="bmd-label-floating">Nome do projeto</label>
                        <input name="nm_projeto" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_empresa['nm_projeto']; ?>" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="bmd-label-floating">Número de EI</label>
                        <input name="nm_ei" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_empresa['nm_ei']; ?>" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="bmd-label-floating">Nome da concessionária</label>
                        <input name="nm_concessionaria" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_empresa['nm_concessionaria']; ?>" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="bmd-label-floating">Cidade</label>
                        <input name="nm_cidade" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_empresa['nm_cidade']; ?>" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="bmd-label-floating">Kilometragem</label>
                        <input name="qnt_kilometragem" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_empresa['qnt_kilometragem']; ?>" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="bmd-label-floating">Quantidade de postes</label>
                        <input name="qnt_postes" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_empresa['qnt_postes']; ?>" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="cadastro" class="bmd-label-floating">Cadastro</label>
                          <input name="cadastro" type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      -->
                  </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Atualizar</button>

```

```
// Classe Projeto Editar.php

<?php
include('../class/classe_verifica_login.php');
include_once('../class/classe_conexao.php');

$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "id", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$nm_empresa = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nm_empresa', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pj_status = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pj_status', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$nm_projeto = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nm_projeto', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$nm_ei = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nm_ei', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$nm_concessionaria = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nm_concessionaria', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$nm_cidade = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nm_cidade', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$qnt_kilometragem = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'qnt_kilometragem', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$qnt_postes = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'qnt_postes', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$conexao->query("UPDATE empresa SET 
                nm_empresa = '$nm_empresa', 
                pj_status = '$pj_status', 
                nm_projeto = '$nm_projeto', 
                nm_projeto = '$nm_projeto', 
                nm_ei = '$nm_ei', 
                nm_concessionaria = '$nm_concessionaria', 
                nm_cidade = '$nm_cidade', 
                qnt_kilometragem = '$qnt_kilometragem', 
                qnt_postes = '$qnt_postes', 
                modificado = NOW()
                WHERE users.id = $id");

if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao)) {
    $_SESSION['sucesso'] = true;
    header("Location: projetos_editar.php?id=$id");
} else {
    $_SESSION['negado'] = true;
    header("Location: projetos_editar.php?id=$id");
}
?>
```
````

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o erro. Retirei includes pois não os tenho como replicar, retirei a parte do banco de dados pois não tenho como a replicar, habilitei o input e o que foi passado meio a requisição post chega inalterado.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá, já verificou o fechamento da tag " "?  Pergunto por que já tive o mesmo problema e há princícipio não enconrei o fechamento da tag no seu código.

Comment: Bom dia, obrigado pela resposta.
Vou testar ao chegar em casa e retorno aqui.

Comment: Bom dia Samuel, acabei conseguindo puxar o meu sistema para o meu trabalho estou ver aqui e não encontrei esta tag que você se refere.

Comment: É que não apareceu o nome da tag  mais seria a `<form></form>` e `<input type="text" name="id" id="id" class="form-control" value="<?php echo 
  $row_empresa['id']; ?>" disabled>` mude para `<input type="hiden" name="id" id="id" class="form-control" value="<?php echo 
  $row_empresa['id']; ?>">` o disable e o fieldset geralmente não deixa capturar valores

Comment: Corrigindo... coloque o campo como oculto ```<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" class="form-control" value="<?php echo    $row_empresa['id']; ?>">``` o disable e o fieldset não deixa capturar valores

Answer (score -2):

O erro ao meu ver se encontra nessa parte do código

```
<div class="col-md-5">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="bmd-label-floating">ID ( Desabilitado )</label>
  <input type="text" name="id" id="id" class="form-control" value="<?php echo 
  $row_empresa['id']; ?>" disabled>
 </div>
</div>
```

Até onde sei formulários desabilitados não são enviados no post, o que voce pode usar é a tag **type="hidden"** no lugar do disabled, porem não vai aparecer na tela

Comment: Pode ser, no meu teste eu habilitei o input e por isso não consegui reproduzir o erro. Agora que testei com ele desabilitada o erro foi reproduzido.

Comment: Bom dia, obrigado pela resposta.
Vou testar ao chegar em casa e retorno aqui.

Comment: Bom dia Augusto Vasques, fiz o teste a pouco e ainda continua resultando erro.
O que notei melhor neste momento e que quando clico em atualizar ele me redireciona para o link projetos_editar.php?id= mas sem o numero do ID da coluna que estou editando.